# Add directory slug to the post (but not custom post type) permalink structure

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, post-type

I'm having an issue trying to set up the default posts post type to use the permalink structure of `/news/%postname%/` - I've tried editing the permalinks but it throws out my other custom post types.

I've currently got two other custom post types; 'careers' and 'case-studies' which use `/careers/%postname%` and `/case-studies/%postname%`

When adding "/news/" into the permalink settings it adds that to the custom post types as well, which I don't want. To help explain, it makes the two custom post types change to `/news/careers/%postname%` etc.

Is there a way I can change the slug or permalink structure of the default "posts" post type or another way around this issue please?

I've tried various solutions and had a good look around for similar issues but they aren't quite the same.

Comment: That has solved my issue! Any reason as to why there is se332921? Can I change that bit and have it still working fine? Thank you! @nmr

Comment: You can freely name a function, as long as it is unique

Comment: Ahh ok just thought it looked rather specific haha. Thank you!